# PHP bugs with comparison operator

Tags: php, compare, operator-keyword

I know the comparison operator of PHP is not 100% because of the automatic type declarations.

I did some tests and found this code

```
<?php
function foo($answer) {
    if ($answer > 10) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return $answer;
    }
}
if (foo(11)) {
    echo "11 is bigger than 10<br />";
}        
if (foo(9)) {
    echo "9 is bigger than 10<br />";
}
?>
```

The output is:

11 is bigger than 10
9 is bigger than 10

Can someone explain me where and why the code fails in this comparison.

Comment: Search a bit more, before declaring a bug. You could however, if this was a more complex problem.

Comment: Just read about booleans as you treat the return value as one: http://php.net/boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `foo()` always returns some value. In this case both boolean and int type. Just make sure you are more strictly when you compare returned value.

```
<?php
function foo($answer) {
    if ($answer > 10) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return $answer;
    }
}

if (foo(11) === true) {
   // This returned TRUE 
   echo "11 is bigger than 10<br />";
}

if ( is_int(foo(9)) === true ) {
   //This returned int 
   echo "9 is bigger than 10<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `return $answer` is truthy in both of your test cases.

This evaluates to:

```
if (11) { ...
if (9) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```
<?php
function foo($answer) {
    return ($answer > 10);
}

if (foo(11)) {
    echo "11 is bigger than 10<br />";
}        
if (foo(9)) {
    echo "9 is bigger than 10<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are comparing it wrong way**, $answer is non zero value and in PHP when you use it in condition every non zero value is consider to be true.

```
function foo($answer) {
    if ($answer > 10) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, better, `return ($answer > 10);`

Comment: You didn't like my edit? @pan

Comment: @PeeHaa: C'mon; you have to know that was hideous.  :)  We should be encouraging fixing the return value, not duct-taping it.

Comment: Oh. I'm all for same return types :)